# 2 бегунка на slider WPF

Tags: c#, slider, wpf

Возможно ли реализовать 2 бегунка на слайдере? что бы к каждому бегунку естественно разные значения приписывались.

Кто что может подсказать и посоветовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать собственный UserControl на основе Slider, и потом использовать этот UserControl там, где вам необходимо. 
По факту, это будут просто два слайдера, наложенные друг на друга, у каждого будет своя тройка - Minimum,Maximum,Value. Для простоты обозначим их за Lower и Upper.

Вот так будет выглядеть XAML возможного UserControl'a

RangeSlider.xaml

```
   <UserControl x:Class="UserControlFun.RangeSlider"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="root">
        <Slider x:Name="LowerSlider"
            Minimum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Minimum}"
            Maximum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Maximum}"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LowerValue}" />
        <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider"
            Minimum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Minimum}"
            Maximum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Maximum}"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=UpperValue}" />

    </UserControl>
```

и его Code-Behind

```
 public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double LowerValue
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double UpperValue
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double Maximum
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));
```

И потом можно его использовать следующим образом:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlFun.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlFun"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel>
            <local:RangeSlider x:Name="slider"
                               Margin="10" 
                               LowerValue="30"
                               UpperValue="70"
                               Minimum="0"
                               Maximum="100"
                               />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Minimum}" Margin="10,1,10,1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=LowerValue}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=UpperValue}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Maximum}" Margin="10,1,10,1" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```